Including a cumulative response as a predictor in a regression? violation or no?
I want to make a longitudinal regression model that looks at something like this:

subject i @ time t: % change in y (t,t-1)  ~ f[ % change in x (t,t-1)]

I had this idea that maybe I could include the cumulative sum of all responses, e.g.

subject i @ time t: % change in y (t,t-1)  ~ f[ % change in x (t,t-1), sum of all y from (t0,t-1)]

I thought that doing this will serve as a reference to show that % change in y depends on how much y has already happened. For example, if we know it usually rains 100 mm in a year and its already rained 90 mm - depending on what time of the year it is, future rain fall could be more or less likely depending on how much rain has already happened. Or the effect  an increased percent of the population taking covid vaccines might be more or less on herd immunity depending on how much of the population has already been vaccinated.
Is it ok to include a cumulative response as a predictor in a regression model? or is this a violation of assumption? I say this because I know that including lagged response as a predictor is a definite violation of statisticals assumption.

Can you add some more details on the model you had in mind? I'm guessing you are thinking of linear regression? It is common to use some if not all of the lagged response in forecasting applications.
